# Can I run Seq.iter's action function asynchronously

Tags: .net, asynchronous, f#, parallel-processing

So, the title describes it all.

```
Seq.iter (fun item -> (*do something*)) sequence
```

Can I run all those lambda-functions as parallel? It can be useful when this function does some big work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, if you are targeting .NET 3.5 +, then

1. Download the [F# PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/)
2. Add a reference to FSharp.PowerPack.Parallel.Seq
3. open Microsoft.FSharp.Collections
4. Code away using PSeq module, e.g. `{1..100} |> PSeq.iter (printfn "%A")`

If you are targeting .NET 2.0, follow my instructions [here](http://projecteulerfun.blogspot.com/2010/05/plinq.html) to compile a back-ported version of `System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable` from the Rx project into the PowerPack `Parallel.Seq` project.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the function in parallel just use the `Parallel.ForEach` function

```
Parallel.ForEach(sequence, fun item -> (* do something *))
```

This works just fine from F#

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Parallel.ForEach`. `Seq.iter` shouldn't be used for that puropse. Watch that

```
Seq.iter (fun n -> printfn "%i" (nth_prime_number n)) { 10 .. 1 }
```

Expecting is

```
29
23
19
17
13
11
7
5
3
2
```

You get anything. For example

```
29
19
23
11
17
13
7
3
2
5
```